# Restrict sensitive information in bluemix without restricting access to space

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have in Bluemix (CF) 1 org and 2 spaces: DEV and PROD.

For DEV developers have full access. For PROD developers assumed to have restricted access.

I read CF documentation about roles, but it did not answer my question fully. I understand that we can do for developers either

- no access at all to PROD scpace (e.g. minimal scope is "space"), or
- make developers read-only access to PROD (but they can read everything).

My question - is there any way to restrict access in the middle of these 2 approaches. For example - hide from developers pieces of sensitive information (passwords) in PROD (we can put them in the environment variables), and have developers read-write access to the rest of PROD space? Because of lack of skilled resources, developers will have to manage PROD space, but possibly without accessing sensitive information (e.g. passwords)

Comment: What do you consider sensitive information in a space? And what are the actions the developer should be able to perform? Could you add more details?

Answer (score 1):

If the only bit of information you need to hide from your developers is those passwords in the app environment variables then you could take these out and store them externally in something like the [Key Protect Service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/key-protect)

The App then calls out to Key Protect, retrieves the passwords and connects to whatever required those passwords.

Obviously the developers can still get access to them if they try, since they can access the app but at least it will reduce the footprint.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented it this way:

1) Developers initially configured PROD space environment.

2) Developers were removed from PROD space, and all other works are done by Org owner. Thus developers connot see PROD space at all (for example in tool chain it just hidden), and deployment and configuring is done by Org owner from now on.